# Xcode 14 and iOS 5.5 simulators

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, screenshot

After updating to Xcode 14 with iOS 16, I'm not seeing any 5.5 devices - makes sense, as Xcode simulators only seem to support one iOS, and none of the 5.5 devices (for instance iPhone 8 Plus) run iOS 16.

However, 5.5 screenshots are still mandatory for the App store. So how do I create these screenshots? The solutions I can think of are these

1. Using physical 5.5 device like iPhone 8 Plus (I don't have one)
2. Downgrade Xcode to version 13 in order to support iOS 15. I would very much like to avoid this, besides some of my Mac setup is Virtual and I am not in control of the Xcode version)

Comment: You can install different iOS versions to be used in the simulator, maybe that brings back a device that has suitable screen size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Download simulators

1. Go to `Window`
2. Select `Devices and Simulators
3. Click on the `plus button` in the bottom left corner.
4. Click on `OS Version` dropdown
5. Select `Download more simulator runtimes`
6. Click on the `plus button` in the bottom left corner.
7. Select `iOS`
8. Select the desired iOS version and wait for the download.
9. Now, you can create a desired simulator with the desired iOS.

### [image]

Remember, you can generate your screenshots based on the device size! and no need for specific simulator by the way.

Comment: Ah I did not know that. I've missed that feature all the way. Thanks a lot! What do you mean with the last comment? Isn't the device screen size specified by the simulator(iPhone)-model?

Comment: You can resize your screenshots to the size which is needed by the store. There is a need for an actual screenshot with the specific device.

Comment: Ok yes, I understand what you mean. However, resizing the image manually will not reflect other differences there might be - for instance the 'notch' or the width/height relation. It will still need to pass the review process, but might not be a problem.

Comment: You shouldn't do that resizing. If apple team understand that you resized your screenshots, they will reject your application.