# Xcode 14.2 no additional simulators

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to add additional device simulator. Product -> Destination -> Add additional simulators window on Xcode. But after adding it to a list of available simulators, it's not appearing in the list of available devices to build.

Show as run destination is checked.

[image: screen]

After clean installing Xcode 14.2, only iPhone 14 simulators are available.

I've tried re-adding several times with different iOS versions on different devices.
I also followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259983/xcode-9-0-simulators-disappeared) and delete all available simulators, as someone suggested. Now I have 0 in a list of devices to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with XCode 14.2 and adding iPhone XR, I went to the Project Navigator pane, selected the top line and on the right side window the Project settings appear. I went to the Minimum Deployments section and selected the lowest IOS version I was working with. In my case I had downloaded and installed iOS 15.5. After that, the IOS simulator list updated with all the simulators Listed in the Devices and Simulators where the "Show as Run Destination" was selected for a given simulator.

Hope this helps...
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am just not sure what you mean with the Project Navigator pane and the top line on the right side window. Could you explain that again maybe? Cause I am having the same issue and can't figure out how to fix it...

Comment: On XCode 14, this is the panel on the very left. To see it, you would go to View->Navigators->Project (or Command 1). This will open the left panel which contains all of your project files. When you select the top line (your project name), your project settings will open in the center area of XCode. Look for the line that says Minimum Deployments. My screenshot above shows the project settings.

Comment: My project's minimum deployment is set to 12.0. Simulators for iOS 13.7 does not show in the list.

Comment: @yoninja This is a different issue. You need to add the simulator, here is a link on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74286315/xcode-14-and-ios-5-5-simulators

Comment: @RoadWarrior, that's what I already did. The iOS 13.7 simulator will not show up as choice for running the app.

Comment: @yoninja You need to open Devices and Simulators XCode->Window->Devices & Simulators, then select the simulators button on the top left, this will show your list of simulators. You then need to click on your version and in the top right corner, select Show Run Destination

Comment: I'm seeing same issue. The 13.7 simulator is installed, min target is set properly, but won't appear in the run dropdown. Devices with iOS 12 appear and run, but the 13 simulator is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that simulators running iOS 13.x and some specific devices runs in "Rosetta"-mode rather than "Apple Silicon".

These devices are hidden by default in the latest Xcode version on macs running with Apple Silicon.
To be able to use these run destinations in Xcode, open the `Product menu -> Destination -> Destination Architectures -> Select "Show Both"`

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730022